# how can i add to into dictionarys value?

Tags: python

i want to add 1 each time a word repeats:

```
def grocery():
    try:
        items = {}
        while True:
            prompt = input('')
            for i in prompt.split():
                items.update({i:1})
            for key, value in items.items():
                if i == key:
                    items[key] += 1
    except EOFError:
        print(items)
        pass

grocery()
```

but it adds 1 to all keys, when my input is :  apple apple banana, it should be {'apple':2,'banana',1}
but it is {'apple':2,'banana',2}

Comment: consider that the 'while True' statement is not an appropriate choice here

Comment: Because `i` in the 2nd loop is "banana" (or whatever is the _last_ value of `i` from the first for loop). You don't need the 2nd for loop. In the same for loop, get the current value of `items[i]`, if it exists, add 1 to it then assign the new value, and if it doesn't set `items[i] = 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example that uses a dictionary's *get()* function.

```
def grocery():
    items = {}
    while (groceries := input('Enter a single item or several items separated by whitespace (Return to quit): ')):
        for item in groceries.split():
            items[item] = items.get(item, 0) + 1
    return items

print(grocery())
```

**Input:**

```
Enter a single item or several items separated by whitespace (Return to quit): apple
Enter a single item or several items separated by whitespace (Return to quit): banana
Enter a single item or several items separated by whitespace (Return to quit): orange apple
Enter a single item or several items separated by whitespace (Return to quit):
```

**Output:**

```
{'apple': 2, 'banana': 1, 'orange': 1}
```

**Note:**

You will need to use Python 3.8 or later in order for the walrus operator (`:=`) to work.